# Virtual Attribute Validation Always Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm separating a datetime column (which yes, I've named 'datetime'... maybe that's too confusing) into two virtual attributes, `date_field` and `time_field`.

Then using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461798/rails-4-convert-datetime-into-separate-date-and-time-fields) I'm recombining the two in a `before_save` callback.

However, now validation **always** fails with "can't be blank" whether or not I've filled in the `date_field` or `time_field`

Here's my model:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :date_field, :time_field, presence: true

  before_save :convert_to_datetime

  def date_field
    datetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") if datetime.present?
  end

  def time_field
    datetime.strftime("%I:%M%p") if datetime.present?
  end

  def date_field=(date)
    @date_field = Date.parse(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  end

  def time_field=(time)
    @time_field = Time.parse(time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end

  def convert_to_datetime
    self.datetime = DateTime.parse("#{@date_field} #{@time_field}")
  end

end
```

**Edit:**

Here's a little new information after investigation:

1) Per xmpolaris's comment, I tried `@date_field || datetime.present? datetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") : nil`, but that returns `nil`

2) I replaced `before_save` with `before_validation` and that gave me a 500 invalid date error.

3) I've inspected the params with byebug and they look like this:

```
(byebug) p params[:date_field]
"2014-02-10"
(byebug) p params[:time_field]
"11:30"
```

Is that the correct format for Rails?

Comment: the attribute readers (date_field, time_field) methods always return nil when you create new record. that's why it fails. you must return virtual attribute if its value is available, otherwise try to read from datetime attribute. e.g. @date_field || datetime.present? datetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") : nil

Comment: Your comment makes a lot of sense to me... but the problem persists exactly as I described even after implementing your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a big headache, it turns out I needed to change my template from this...

`<input type="text" id="time_field" name="time_field">`

to this:

`<input type="text" id="time_field" name="lesson[time_field]">`

The parameters were not even being set in the first place.

Does anyone have any idea why this is necessary? And if it's possible to change this behavior?

Additionally, xmpolaris was right in his comment. It was also necessary to change my getters to:

```
def date_field
  @date_field || datetime ? datetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") : nil
end

def time_field
  @time_field || datetime ? datetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") : nil
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem I can see is:

---

**Not Set**

`before_save` runs *after* validation (`before_validation` runs *before* validation)

I see you're using [Ruby setters & writers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774837/what-would-a-default-getter-and-setter-look-like-in-rails) to create the virtual attributes. However, your `date_field` and `time_field` setters are only running if `datetime` is present

From your code, `datetime` is only present when you set the datetime attribute in your `before_save` callback, which means you're not going to have `datetime` available for your setters

I would try this:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_validation :convert_to_datetime
end
```

Although might help a little, I don't think this will work completely

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment! I tried `before_validation`, but it gives me a 500 date invalid error, for both valid inputs and missing inputs.